# In Ruby on Rails, why do some gems require config/initializers/foo.rb and some gems don't?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, rubygems

For example, I think the gems such as `haml` doesn't need a file in `config/initializers/`, while `devise` needs a `config/initializers/devise.rb`.

Why do some gems not need an initializer file and some do?  Can they all be made to be without one or all require one?  What's the rule?

Answer (score 0):

Some gems need more configuration than others, usually when the functionality is related to an account or needs to be manually configured to work with your specific rails apps (like hoptoad_notifier and devise), other gems provide or add in more general functionality in your rails apps, often these will work without any configuration but do have some flexibility and can be customized with an initialiser (like haml and will_paginate).